# Omniauth with instagram authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, omniauth

I want to build an authentication system in my rails app with instagram, Does omniauth support instagram? or do I have to use the instagram gem instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all, the gem instagram is more efficient than omniauth, its documentation is reliable and very constructive to use, for further person who'd wonder like me, you can go with instagram gem.